# Extract 2 strings from an NSString separated by a special character

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

i have an NSString like "Hello - this is me".
I want to search for the "-" and put the text before and after the "-" in two separate strings.

Anyone knows how to do that the best way?

greets Max

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
NSArray *subStrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]; //or rather @" - "
NSString *firstString = [subStrings objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lastString = [subStrings objectAtIndex:1];
//Add some array range checking to it and you're done.
```

Comment: How a highly localized and trivial snippet like this could attract all those upvotes is beyond me?!

Comment: Worked fine,but if I have a string like this @"cat@animal,pen@thing,mouse@hardware" what would be the ideal approach to form an array holding @"cat,pen,mouse",i.e. trimming the special character @ and text after it in each string,please note it is a single string,please help,thanks :)

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: Regex matching. Catch group 1 of pattern `@"(?<=,|^)(\w+?)@\w+?(?=,|$)"`. For more help, please consider posting a separate question altogether.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get you,catch group 1 of pattern??? ,I apologize I don't want to post questions for each and every issue,so far it was my story.Please understand :)

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: [read up on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), specifically on "catch/capture groups". Regex is OT in this question.

Comment: I don't understand what is asked what is answered

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: Then ask a specific (and separate) question and please stop spamming this unrelated question. Or better yet (do this, actually): do some research on your own on regex and use of "capture/catch groups" yourself. It's no rocket science. [/OT]

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString *myString = @"123-456-789-1234-2345-3456-4567";
NSArray *subStrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
for (int i = 0; i < [subStrings count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"string on array position %d is : %@", i, [subStrings objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```