# Break NSString Into Two NSStrings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am parsing an xml source where i am getting the following string.

```
   "This Is A Title String - This Is A Source"
```

What i need to do is to break the above string into two parts, one with the text before the "-" character and one after it and save them into separate NSStrings. Can anyone help me to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: have you try to read NSString document?

Comment: You need to read the NSString spec.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614681/extract-2-strings-from-an-nsstring-separated-by-a-special-character?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method:

```
NSArray *parts = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method on NSString called: `componentsSeparatedByString`
For example:

```
NSString *myString = @"This Is A Title String - This Is A Source"; 
NSArray *splitStrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString: @"-"];
```

splitStrings will contain two strings, "This Is A Title String" and "This Is A Source"